# regex issue with php

Tags: php, regex, web

For a PHP project I need to fetch data from a second-hand car website that doesn't have an API. To pull the data, I'm using file_get_contents() in PHP to get all the HTML and regex to find the data I'm looking for.

This is (a piece) of the data I'm using:

```
<!-- begin Site parameters -->
sSite="autoscout24.nl";
sZone="used_car_detail";
adParams ={"make": "9","model": "1624","price": "2","fr": "7","miles": "10","art": "1","ad": "dealer","zip": "NL4264 AT","zip2": "4264 AT","did": "12865153","seal": "146","seg": "de_oem,mass_oem,compact,old_fr,high_miles,low_price,high_hp","hp": "7","acc": "U","vat": "0","fuel": "B","gear": "M","carno": "74RTBJ","carby": "0","ECO": "NO","equi": "1,2,3,5,12,13,17,30,31,32,38,49,126,127","type": "U","cost": "7450","img": "http://pic2.autoscout24.net/images/010/472/0257472010001.jpg","stmak": "Audi","stmod": "A3","sthp": "150","stkw": "110","age": "108","styea": "2005","stmon": "8","stmil": "232375","stccm": "1984","eutax": "0","ken": "74RTBJ","kenteken": "true","carid": "257472010","width": "3","test": "off","rnd": "72"};
<!-- end Site parameters -->
```

Now, the bit I want to select is '74RTBJ' (without quotes). I'm trying to use

```
/"ken": "(.*?)",/sig
```

to do so but that selects

```
 /"ken": "74RTBJ",
```

How do I get it to only select the bit I want? Again, I'm using PHP's preg_match_all() to find the data, I heard that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/yX3eB5/4 .your regex is working fine.

Comment: Another approach would be to get the javascript object with a regex like `/adParams =(.+?);/` and then do a `json_decode()` on the matched group.

Comment: @vks I thought so too but when I enter the exact same thing in PHP, it returns /"ken": "74RTBJ",

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I know, but my manager said 'he preferred otherwise' for no apparent reason, but hey, screw that, I'm going to do it anyway. Thanks ;)

Comment: Exactly. You're the programmer. It doesn't matter what he's preferring when it depends on code solutions ;-).

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER + now I won't be messing around with it all day ; ) Have a good day man

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all` has third argument, which is a reference to array of matched groups. In your case a value between quotes is captured under index 1.

```
preg_match_all('/"ken": "(.*?)",/sig', <your-string-here>, $matches);
```

And now:

```
$matches[0] == '"ken": "74RTBJ",'
```

while

```
$matches[1] == '74RTBJ'
```

More information: http://php.net//manual/pl/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Not in my case for some reason :( Anyway, I'm doing it slightly differently now and it works and as this'll work for most people, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lookbehind or `\K` in your regex to match the value of the field `Ken`,

```
\bken":\s*"\K[^"]*
```

OR

```
(?<=\bken": ")[^"]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xM0rC9/3)